# click event not triggered in the external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a library code that can be used across all my html pages.
I am very new to JS and this is the first code that I am trying to write like a library function.

I have a text field and a button next to it, on click of the button this adds a another text field below and a button next to it, this also removes the button in previous line.

I managed to do a button in the same row and adding text field in next lines, but the button click for newly added methods are not working with pure JS so I tried to use jquery "on" click event. For some reason its not getting triggered in my case.
Not sure what I am missing.

**Code in external file**

```
var addAnother = {
    addAnotherField: function (eventTrigger, fieldContainer, arrayField) {
        console.log("called");
        var eventTrigger = eventTrigger;
        console.log("ready called", eventTrigger);
        $(document).on('click', eventTrigger, function (e) {
            console.log("click called");
            var buttonText = this.value;
            var div = document.getElementById(fieldContainer);
            var element = document.getElementById(eventTrigger);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = arrayField;
            div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            div.appendChild(input);
            var button = document.createElement("input");
            button.type = "button";
            button.id = eventTrigger;
            button.value = buttonText;
            div.appendChild(button);
        });
    }
}
```

**code in HTML**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    addAnother.addAnotherField("addAnother", "addAnotherContainer", "fieldArray[]");
});
```

Working JS code:
http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/ekoob8f0/

next button non working code JS
http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/ukseeuak/

with Jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/balasivagnanam/6ea2dk6m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
/** this part will be located in another file added as a js library */
function addAnother(elem) {
    var text = $("#addAnotherField").clone();
    $("<br/>").insertBefore($("#addAnother"));
    text.insertBefore($("#addAnother"));

}
/* this part will be coded below the above code file in the html file*/

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addAnother').click(function () {
        addAnother(this);
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e05xyx26/)